# How fast can a bullet go before it starts to evaporate/break up due to air friction?

Tags: hard-science

If you fired a standard 9x19mm Parabellum and then somehow magically accelerated it to Mach 10, would it survive the trip, and if so, would it still be an effective projectile? What are the factors that go into this?

Comment: JHP, FMJ, or straight hollowpoint, first off?

Comment: What material? 9x19mm Parabellum is now a pretty wide family of bullets.

Comment: Note: at mach 10, belly button lint can be lethal.   What are you using to measure "effective projectile?"  For example, are you concerned with the aerodynamics of a bullet flying at 10x its intended speed, or do we also magically assume it hits the target?

Answer (score 1):

Supersonic velocities at low altitudes causes large amounts of heating due to friction. Standard small arms bullets have a lead core with a copper jacket. Lead has a very low melting point, and copper sort of a mediumish melting point. Neither has anywhere near the performance necessary to handle the thermal stress of mach 10, low altitude flight for more than a split second. Also, both metals are fairly soft and would likely deform under the tremendous aerodynamic loading involved.

Still, the bullets would be extremely lethal at short ranges (say less than 50 feet). At this speed, 9mm bullets would resemble tiny shaped charges or explosively formed penetrators, in that they are composed of an extremely high velocity jet of a dense metal. These bullets would cut through several inches of steel and still kill whatever was behind that. When they impacted, the result would be like a small explosion.

Eventually, if the bullet did not hit a target it would heat up enough to break apart - likely into a fine powder which would likely oxidize. The end result would be lead and copper oxide powder sprinkled over hundreds of feet.

Special tungsten armor piercing bullets might survive the trip intact (say if shot upward so it didn't impact with anything). They would travel considerably further than bullets in non-magical situations. It looks like people are saying that a 9mm bullet can travel as far as 2km. http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2002/DomnaAntoniadis.shtml That's at roughly mach 1, so you're 10 times faster than that. I can't find any trajectory calculators which take air resistance into account, but the numbers without air resistance are staggering. Range is 1,200km and altitude peaks at 300km! http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html#tra7 With an atmosphere, the bullet would only reach a tiny fraction of those distances.